# try to proxy remote destop(3389) by nodejs socket pipe, but fail

Tags: node.js, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to proxy remote destop(3389) to port 8889.

```
var net = require('net');
var client_port = 8889;
var host = '127.0.0.1';
host = '192.168.7.69'; 

var client = net.createServer(function(c) {
    var loc = net.connect(3389, host, function() {
      console.log('connet to 3389 success.');
      loc.pipe(c);
      c.pipe(loc);
    });
}).listen(client_port, host, function(c) {
  console.log('proxy opened, visit: %j',client.address());
});
```

then use win7's remote destop, visit myself, it fail.

**update:**

the remotedestop connect show "connet to 127.0.0.1:8889" for a long time, and timeout.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, change the order.

```
var net = require('net');
var client_port = 8889;
var host = '127.0.0.1';
host = '192.168.7.69'; 

var client;
var loc = net.connect(3389, host, function() {
  console.log('connet to 3389 success.');
  client = net.createServer(function(c) {
    loc.pipe(c);
    c.pipe(loc);
  }).listen(client_port, host, function(c) {
    console.log('proxy opened, visit: %j',client.address());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `host` variable, first assigns `'127.0.0.1'` and in the line below you assing `'192.168.7.69'`, maybe this is the problem

```
var host = '127.0.0.1',
    host2 = '192.168.7.69'
```

Comment: it isn't. I try to connet at diffrent host, and use win7's remote destop to test, both fail